# How to make SQLite SELECT query in C correctly?

Tags: c, sqlite, select, utf-8

I want to make query like this one:

```sql
SELECT lyrics FROM cache WHERE author=%s0, title=%s1 LIMIT 1;
```

where strings `%s0` and `%s1` should be substituted. Assuming strings are *not* sanitized, UTF-8 encoded (As database itself), simple null-terminated `char*` arrays. What are my options to do this? Are there any built-in functions in SQLite (C API) for this?

Comment: Are you looking for the [prepared statement interface](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html), to avoid injection attacks?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for. It's local database, so there can be no attacks. Still, arbitrary value can cause bugs if not escaped in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like mentioned in comments already prepared statements should be used.

**Why Prepared Statements Should Be Favoured**

When you create SQL queries yourself as a string, they almost always contain parts of a user's input. An attacker can take advantage of this by, for example, cleverly changing the semantics of the query using `'` and thus gaining unauthorized access to data or destroying data.

This is called SQL injection and is one of the top most critical security risks, see here:
https://www.owasp.org/images/7/72/OWASP_Top_10-2017_%28en%29.pdf.pdf

**Defense**

> The use of prepared statements with variable binding (aka parameterized queries) is how all developers should first be taught how to write database queries.

https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#defense-option-1-prepared-statements-with-parameterized-queries

**How to use prepared statements with SQLite**

For prepared statements see https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html.

Basic steps are:

- create the prepared statement
- bind values to parameters
- run the SQL
- destroy the object to avoid resource leaks

**Example**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "sqlite3.h"

void exit_with_error(sqlite3 *db, const char * msg) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", msg, sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    sqlite3_close(db);
    exit(1);
}

int main() {
    sqlite3 *db;
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

    int rc = sqlite3_open("path-to-lyrics", &db);

    if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
        exit_with_error(db, "can't open db: ");

    //create prepared statement
    rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "SELECT lyrics FROM cache WHERE author=?1 AND title=?2 LIMIT 1;", -1, &stmt, 0);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
        exit_with_error(db, "failure fetching data: ");

    //bind values to parameters
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, "Don Brownrigg", -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, "Just Breathe", -1, SQLITE_STATIC);

    //run the SQL
    rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
    if (rc == SQLITE_ROW) {
        printf("%s\n", sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0));
    }

    //destroy the object to avoid resource leaks
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

    sqlite3_close(db);    

    return 0;
}
```

**Build**

With CMake it could look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(sqlitequery C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

add_executable(sqlitequery main.c)

target_link_libraries (sqlitequery sqlite3)
```

On command line one could build with something like:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra main.c -lsqlite3 -o sqlitequery
```

Comment: That's what I needed. Thanks for exhaustive explanation (: