# Why am i not able to create two new users in SQLite connected to C? It doesnt work for two calls

Tags: sql, c, database, sqlite

I am not able to figure out why this this happens. What could be the logical mistake or how could i solve it. Actually the issues is even if i execute a customer login(not part of the code here) then try a signup same problem occurs. But i can do multiple login and log out. I can create a new user and login using that

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include "sqlite3.c" 
char output[5][30];//to save result
int temp;//global variable to be used in callback again
typedef struct usr{char name[15],pass[15];int uid;}USER;
static int callback(void *data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
{
    int i;
    temp=argc;//stores number of return values
    printf("\n*%d*\n",argc);
    for(i=0;i<argc;i++)
    {
        strcpy(output[i],argv[i]);
        printf("*%s* ",argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
void INSERTC()
{
    printf("\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tCustomer Signup");
    sqlite3 *db;
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    int t,rc,*data;
    char sql[150],name[30],pass[30];
    printf("\n\tEnter your Username : ");
    scanf("%s",name);
    printf("\n\tEnter your Password : ");
    scanf("%s",pass);
    rc = sqlite3_open("trail1.db", &db);
    sprintf(sql, "SELECT userid FROM customer WHERE username='%s';",name);
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql,callback,(void*)data, &zErrMsg);//callback is called for every line in result
    if(temp==0)
    {   
        strcpy(sql,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customer;");
        rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql,callback,(void*)data, &zErrMsg);
        t=atoi(output[0]);
        sprintf(sql,"INSERT INTO customer(userid,username,password) VALUES(%d,'%s','%s');",t,name,pass);
        rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql,callback,(void*)data, &zErrMsg);
        printf("\n\tSuccessfully Registered.\n");
        printf("\n\tUser Id Alloted : %d",t);
        sqlite3_close(db);
    }
    else
        printf("\n\tUsername already taken!");
    printf("\n\n\tPress Enter to continue...");
    getchar();getchar();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    INSERTC();//First call
    INSERTC();//Second call
    return 0;
}
```

[Table before code execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDvci.png)[Code execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4No2.png)

In the code what i do is search for given username and if the query returns no results i insert the record. If it does return then it prints username already taken.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1**

You make your decision whether a user name is already taken based on a variable `temp`.

This one is set to the argc parameter of the callback. When you run through your first INSERTC call, then the callback for the following statement `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customer` sets `temp` to 1, since there is one result column `COUNT(*)`. The actual result comes as string with the argv parameter of the callback.

Documentation says:

> The 2nd argument to the sqlite3_exec() callback function is the number of columns in the result. The 3rd argument to the sqlite3_exec() callback is an array of pointers to strings obtained as if from sqlite3_column_text(), one for each column.

see https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html

**Problem 2**

But actually it seems you want to check `temp` that with the `SELECT userid FROM customer WHERE username='%s'` before. But if no record with matching username is found, the callback is not called.

**Data Pointer**

The pointer *data is never initialized.

> The 4th argument to sqlite3_exec() is relayed through to the 1st argument of each callback invocation.

Since you don't use the data pointer you could just pass NULL. If you want to make use of it, make sure you initialize it.

**Return Codes**

sqlite3 functions return a code that indicates whether an operation was successful or not. You should check whether the operation was successful and take appropriate action if it fails (for example, print an error message to stderr and end with an error code).

**Closing Database Connection**

You call sqlite3_close only in the if branch. But you should close it independent of results.

**Better Use Prepared Statements**

Instead of using sprintf to create your own SQL that contains unchecked external user input, you should use prepared statements. Using unchecked user input could lead to one of the top most critical security risks, known as SQL injection.

Therefore it is better to use sqlite3_prepare_v2(), sqlite3_step() and sqlite3_finalize(). Basically sqlite3_exec is just a convenient wrapper around these calls anyway. For an example of how to use it, you can have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/57505795/2331445.

Another advantage of this approach would be that you would process the SQL calls and associated results in the same place.